# Retrieving parameters from PUT request

Tags: symfony

In Symfony2, I'm trying to set up a controller that responds to PUT requests and retrieves parameters from the headers associated with the request (which I'm entering using Postman). The page is loading fine, but is not getting any values from the headers.

This is my `routing.yml` file:

```
mybundle_foo:
    pattern: /foo
    defaults: {_controller: myBundle:Default:foo }
    requirements: {_methods: put, _format: html}
```

In the controller:

```
public function fooAction (Request $request) {
  $someParam = $request->request->get('someParam');
  return new Response("Some param is $someParam", 200);
}
```

When sending a PUT request to the URL with Postman, with a header with a key of "someParam" and a value of "bar," the output I get is just `Some param is`

I had thought that you would get the headers in the same way as you do with a POST request, but I guess not. Is there any way to get the headers for a PUT request?

Answer (score 2):

To get a parameter from the header:

```
$someParam = $request->headers->get("someParam");
```

Comment: this saved my life lol 4:57am, no sleep, doing some technical exam requirement lol. Symfony is a very complicated version of Laravel :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem in `$request->request`. You should use:

```
$request->get('someParam');
```

Also check this in your controller:

```
var_dump($_PUT['someParam']);
```

Comment: Just tried that. Same result. Trying to var_dump the $_PUT superglobal made Symfony throw an error that there's no _PUT variable. $_POST worked, but Symfony complained there's no 'someParam' index, which makes sense since it's a PUT request and not POST.